# Concatenate numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I want to concatenate three 1 dimensional numpy arrays (x1, x2, x3) to one array X (3 columns). I already tried the concatenate function but I think I am doing something wrong. At least I got an error message:

I tried the following:

```
X = np.concatenate([x1, x2, x3], axis = 1)
```

As well as:

```
X = np.concatenate((x1, x2, x3), axis = 1)
```

Both times I got an error:

```
Error: IndexError: axis 1 out of bounds [0, 1)
```

How to use the concatenate function correct? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Since they are 1d, there's no `axis=1`.  You have to to turn the arrays into 2d first.  That's what all the answers do before using `concatenate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
np.column_stack((x1, x2, x3))
```

To me this is more expressive, does what you want, and has an intuitive name with one less argument required.

Comment: @Rchieve: if this solved your problem, you can "accept" this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: @ John Zwinck: Thanks for the hint! There was a 'delay'. I wasn't able to checkmark the answer during the first 10 minutes! Now it's done! (:

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`numpy.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html). Try:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.vstack([x1, x2, x3])
```

The size of `x1`, `x2` and `x3` must be the same.

Comment: You say hstack in one place but vstack in another.  Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use `concatenate` is to reshape the arrays so they are `(n,1)` 2d array.  Here's what `np.column_stack` does

```
In [222]: x1=np.arange(3);x2=np.arange(10,13);x3=np.arange(20,23)
In [230]: ll=[x1,x2,x3]

In [231]: np.concatenate([np.array(i, copy=False, ndmin=2).T for i in ll], axis=1)

Out[231]: 
array([[ 0, 10, 20],
       [ 1, 11, 21],
       [ 2, 12, 22]])
```

Though I think this is more readable:

```
In [233]: np.concatenate([i[:,None] for i in ll],axis=1)
Out[233]: 
array([[ 0, 10, 20],
       [ 1, 11, 21],
       [ 2, 12, 22]])
```

`np.vstack` does

```
In [238]: np.concatenate([np.atleast_2d(i) for i in ll],axis=0)
Out[238]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [20, 21, 22]])
```

but in this case requires a further `transpose` to get columns.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has a [stack function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) (since NumPy 1.10). This allows you to concatenate along any dimension, as long as it makes sense (eg can't concatenate 1-d arrays along 3rd dimension).

For example, pairing up the elements of two 1-D arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> b = np.array([-1, -2, -3, -4])
>>> np.stack((a, b), 1)
array([[ 1, -1],
       [ 2, -2],
       [ 3, -3],
       [ 4, -4]])
```

(Note the input argument is a tuple of np.arrays)